# AngularJS : Using inject in e2e tests to catch some events

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, testing, angularjs-e2e

I want to write a e2e test (which checks if form is submitted) as a part of testing directive that I've put as a attribute on a form element and I want to achieve something like this:

```
element.bind('submit', function (e){
 console.log('submitted');
});
```

How can I catch some event, e.g. submission of form or some event emitted by the children elements?

Can I use angular mocks somehow and inject for instance a $scope, to check evaluation on submission function?
I play around and I've tried a few ways, but finally I've concluded that this works only for unit tests, am I right? 
Or there are a some ways to test in e2e if form was submitted or if some event was fired?